# Yet Another "Why isn't my Favicon showing?"

Tags: html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, icons, favicon

## Update

---

I have just tried "Pinning" my site to the Taskbar again (after removing it) but when I clicked and held down the mouse button on the 16x16px icon inside the address bar (see pic below), you can see my favicon being dragged around with the mouse - so internet explorer has found and got the icon - it's just not displaying it in all the right places! Also updated code below:
[image]

---

As the title suggests, I can't get my favicon to display; in any version of any browser. There is 1 exception, though - which isn't good enough:

IE 9 and IE 10 -
[image]

As you can probably see in the screenshot above, the *only* time I get to see my favicon is after I've added it to my Favorites folder and opened the Favorites Bar. The favicon does *not* display in the Tab (next to the page title), it does not display in the Taskbar area, and it does not display up the top-left of the browser window if I have "Pinned" my site to the Taskbar.

In every other browser, it simply does not display at all.

I have tried every possible "solution" that I could find online.

Here's the code I have:

```
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://www.mysite.com/favicon.ico"><!-- Major Browsers -->
    <!--[if IE]><link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.mysite.com/favicon.ico"/><![endif]--><!-- Internet Explorer-->
```

I have also tried all common sizes for the favicon; `16x16`, `32x32`, `64x64`, `128x128` and `256x256` - and I've even tried saving all sizes within the same `*.ico` file.

I have tried deleting the cache file for `*.ico` files.

Nothing has worked. The exact same code has previously worked on other sites that I've made. I don't get it. What gives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I've edited this answer, leaving only solution to problem presented in question.**

Use: `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{ICONURL}"/>`

Instead of: `<link rel="icon" href="{ICONURL}"/>`

Comment: Thank you. That's another one I tried but forgot to mention, sorry. I tried PNG after I tried ico, neither of them worked. But, I've just discovered something very, very strange (see updated question)

Comment: Replace `rel="icon"` with `rel="shortcut icon"` in every browser, not IE only.

Comment: Yeah, *.png files work too, as poepje said; that's what I used to use in other sites after I read an article saying that browsers now support PNG "icon" files

Comment: Excellent! Your comment fixed my problem, @djmati11 - thank you so much! I'm surprised how many articles and tutorials out there either have the wrong information or just outdated information in them, can make things really confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my site just now.  Drove myself crazy trying to get an favicon.ico file to work.  What finally got it working correctly for me in IE 11 (on Windows 7), was to dump the favicon.ico file completely and go with a PNG instead:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon-32x32.png" type="image/png"/>
```

I used a PNG file with a transparency layer. Once I did this and uploaded my page, IE began displaying the icon correctly in the Tabs (and the shortcuts/bookmarks) on the very next page refresh.  I double checked and it looks like Chrome and Firefox are cool with this as well.

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
<link rel="icon"
      type="image/ico"
      href="Link Goes Here">
```

If putting the favicon in a folder:

```
<link rel="icon"
      type="image/ico"
      herf="Folder/Subfolder"
```

Make sure the code is in the head tag.
Make sure the image is in the .ico format; It won't work otherwise.