# Google Chrome is showing me tomcat icon instead of my favicon

Tags: google-chrome, tomcat, favicon

I have an icon favicon.ico its a little orange monster, but when I show my page in chrome I always get the cat from tomcat, my icon works great in FF and IE10 and it used to work on chrome but now doesn't work, I've tried refreshing it and putting different icons on my page but still nothing, I think this happened since my last update, but I can't say it for sure, I really wasn't paying attention for the difficulty in refreshing those icons in chrome.

I have now Versión 24.0.1312.56

My app is hosted by tomcat as I work with servlets buy this hadn't ever been an issue before.

Now when I try to call the icon directly going to:

```
(http://localhost:8080/mysite/favicon.ico)
```

chrome downloads it instead of showing it.

I haven't published the site as it is for a local service so I can't show the page but here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

  <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
  <%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
  <fmt:setLocale value='es-US'/>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
      <title>Anicom administrativo - Inicio</title>
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../images/favicon.ico" />
```

I've looked everywhere but I haven't seemed to find the answer, also I recently changed the site to HTML5 but that didn't seemed to be a problem :(

I've tried putting it in the root folder and calling it with an absolute href but that didn't worked either.

I also changed the icon in different sizes and formats, from png to ico and that didn't worked either.

I run out of ideas... I tried cleaning the favicons folder but somehow I couldn't find it :P also I have several chrome users with old versions of the icon working and I don't know how to refresh it for them tried ctrl+shift+R and deleting the cache and none of this worked :(

Hope you can help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the Developer Tools `(Ctrl+Shift+I)` to view the network tab while loading the page to see what request it is making for the favicon?  It may be serving something from the browser's cache rather than hitting your server.  If you are seeing the correct thing in other browsers, that makes me think the problem is not on the file on the server, but may be something like this instead.  You may need to clear browsing data `(Ctrl+Shift+Delete)` to empty the cache.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310718/yet-another-why-isnt-my-favicon-showing?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I tried this things and you where right I was uploading an old favicon, I also had it in my favorites bar and it was taking it from here, but now its not uploading any of my favicons :S and when I try to go directly with `(localhost:8080/mysite/images/favicon.ico)` chrome downloads it, instead of showing it, I have chrome on mac, could that be it?

Comment: Did you mean this as a comment on my answer?

Comment: Yes I did! when I tried to put it as a comment it didn't let me so I thougth I had to put it as another answer.

Comment: I tried what you told me and the tomcat icon disappeared but my icon never got shown.

Comment: And somehow now the tomcat favicon returned :S